# How to have multiple sequential transform transitions?

Tags: css

I am trying to replicate the hamburger menu icon of Apple https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro-13/ if you open it in mobile, you will see it, it has 2 lines and when you click it:

1. First the top goes down to the middle and the bottom goes up to the middle
2. Once they meet they are rotated 45 degrees to form a cross

The question is how do I "queue" transforms to recreate that animation?

I tried to do the following:

.clockwiseAnimation {
transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
transform: translateY(0.25rem) rotate(45deg);
}

.counterclockwiseAnimation {
transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
transform: translateY(-0.2rem) rotate(-45deg);
}

Both lines, do go to the correct spot, but the animations are not separated. They just form the cross.

Comment: https://codepen.io/rylanharper/pen/MoqBeG

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez yes, thanks, I already have that working, if you look at the animation on apples website, first it translates and AFTER translation it does rotation